# Keeping the last row in a month and year for a particular group

Tags: powerquery

I have a table which contains roughly 30 columns. One of the columns is "Date" and one is "Project Code". For each project code, there could be multiple entries in the table for a given month and year. For example, for project code "ABC" there could be multiple entries for February, 2020. Each would have a different date (i.e, 20200202, 20200209, 20200216, 20200223, 20200229)

In Power Query, I'd like to perform a transformation step that includes only those rows that represent the last entry for a month and year, for each project code. Using the example above, I want a single row for project "ABC", for February, 2020, and it would be for the date of 20200229.

I immediately looked at Group By but I don't think I'm going to be able to do what I want using Group By.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something along these lines

Assuming column **Date** is formatted as a date then ...

Add a column to pull out the month using

```
= Date.Month([Date])
```

Add a column to pull out the year using

```
= Date.Year([Date])
```

Add a column that finds the maximum date from all the rows with matching (Group, Month, Year)

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStep","MaxDate",(i)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStep", each [Project Code]=i[Project Code] and [Month]=i[Month] and [Year]=i[Year]) [Date]), type date )
```

Add a column to compare current date to that maximum date

```
=if [Date]=[MaxDate] then "keep" else "remove"
```

Remove the rows that don't match by filtering

Remove the extra columns

Sample code below

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project Code", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Month", each Date.Month([Date])),
#"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Year", each Date.Year([Date])),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom3","MaxDate",(i)=>List.Max(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom3", each [Project Code]=i[Project Code] and [Month]=i[Month] and [Year]=i[Year]) [Date]), type date ),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Match", each if [Date]=[MaxDate] then "keep" else "remove"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Match] = "keep")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"MaxDate", "Match","Month","Year"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

With Table.Group:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("TcwxCsAwDEPRu3jOIMkxScf2GiH3v0Y9uDRgLY+P1zJByJM1u3MEbLdiEsVRyAvS/Nr4U2mUej8eOEvVzzZSntz0Q8FSDtv7BQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), {"Date","Project","SomeData"}),
    types = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", Int64.Type}, {"Project", type text}, {"SomeData", Int64.Type}}),
    year = Table.AddColumn(types, "year", each Number.RoundDown([Date]/10000)),
    month = Table.AddColumn(year, "month", each Number.RoundDown(Number.Mod([Date],10000)/100)),
    day = Table.AddColumn(month, "day", each Number.Mod([Date],100)),
    group = Table.Group(day, {"Project", "year", "month"}, {"temp", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{"day",1}),1)}),
    combine = Table.Combine(group[temp])
in
    combine
```

Initial data:

[image]

Result:

[image]